# How to return current state and setState conditionally in React?

Tags: reactjs, methods, state

I need to call method where I can return current state and change it in certain condition.
What am I doing wrong??

This is my state:

```
  this.state = {
            input: {
                amount: "20000",
   }
  }
```

This is my method:

```
methodHandler = () => {
    const {input} = this.state;
    if(condition){
        this.setState({input: { ...this.state.input, amount: 55000}})
    }
    return input.amount
   
}
```

This is how I am trying to call it:

```
<p>{this.methodHandler} </p>
```

I also tried this:

```
 <p>{this.methodHandler()} </p>
```

and this:

```
 <p>{() => this.methodHandler()} </p>
```

Nothing works

Comment: Sorry for confusing everybody, I've been using curly braces

Answer (score 0):

You need to use curly braces in order to embed data inside the jsx.

Try like this:

{this.methodHandler}

Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx

Comment: Sorry for confusing everybody, I've been using curly braces